# How can I save the scrollback history of every window/pane in a tmux session?

Tags: shell, terminal, tmux, tty

I'd like to save the complete scrollback history of every window/pane in a tmux session into one file per pane.

I know how to do it in the active pane:

```
tmux capture-pane -pJ -S - > log.txt
```

But, I can't figure out, how to go through all the panes in a session.

The script can be run from within the session, or outside, either way works for me.